# Where can I download AppleScript Studio?

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-studio

I've heard about [AppleScript Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Related_scripting_issues) many times, but I cannot find any download links.

A tutorial said that I could launch Xcode and select AppleScript under Application when starting a new project, but there wasn't anything listed, which had anything to do with AppleScript.

How can I download AppleScript Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AppleScript Studio was the name used to describe creating an AppleScript application using Xcode, not a separate application. Apple no longer uses the name, and it is called a Cocoa-AppleScript application.
[image]

Comment: note that Cocoa-AppleScript applications are not the same as the old AppleScript Studio applications.

Answer (score 4):

AppleScript Studio is no longer included in Xcode as of Xcode 4. But there is [AppleScriptObjC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/_index.html), a framework which lets you write Cocoa apps using AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you don't already have Xcode, download it from here: http://developer.apple.com/xcode/.  As mentioned above, AppleScript Studio doesn't exist anymore as Xcode supersedes it.